# Do you need an IDP for Lebanese drivers licenses in Sweden?

Tags: legal, sweden

The Lebanese drivers license is in Arabic and French, and the Swedish passport is in Swedish, English and French. French is a 3rd language of many Swedes and our king is French.

Do you need an IDP for Lebanese drivers licenses in Sweden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Swedish Transport Agency](https://transportstyrelsen.se/en/road/Driving-licences/frequently-asked-questions-faq-about-foreign-driving-licences/):

> Am I allowed to drive in Sweden with a foreign driving licence?
>
> Yes, provided you have your driving licence with you when driving.
>   Either your driving licence must have a photograph of yourself on it
>   or you must, when driving, also have a valid ID document with you
>   containing a photo. If your driving licence has not been issued in
>   English, German **or French**, the police may also require you to have
>   with you a certified translation of your driving licence. An
>   international driving licence is a certified translation that can be
>   used for this purpose.

Since your license *has* been issued in French, it appears that you *do not* need an IDP or any other certified translation.